# Match digits in [g]awk

Tags: regex, awk, posix-ere

I'm stumped! Trying to write an awk regex to match a string against 11 digits.

I've tried:

```
if (var ~ /^[0-9]{11}$/ )
if (var ~ /^([0-9]){11}$/ )
if (var ~ /^([0-9]{11})$/ )
if (var ~ /^[0-9]{11}/ ) # altho I really do need to check the whole str
if (var ~ /[0-9]{11}/ )
```

If I use this....

```
if (var ~ /^[0-9]+/ )
```

Then I get a match - but I need to check for exactly 11 digits.

Comment: Which awk are you using (gawk vs nawk vs /usr/xpg4/bin/awk vs ...)? Which version of that awk (awk --version)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You described your problem, but didn't tell us your awk version. It is an important information.

but this may work for your case:

```
if (var ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && length(var)==11)
```

If we know the version, there could be simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to match *exactly* 11 *consecutive* digits someplace in the string:

Using the test file:

```
hi12345678910
hi1234
```

The windows version of awk command line:

```
awk --posix "{ if ($1 ~ /[0-9]{11}/) print}" testfile.txt
```

It printed:

```
hi12345678910
```

Comment: If you just want regexp intervals and have an old version of gawk, use --re-interval rather than --posix since the latter disables all gawk extensions like gensub(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Doh - forgot to RTM:

```
              Interval expressions are only available if either --posix or
              --re-interval is specified on the command line.
```

Comment: That is only for old version of gawk. Get a recent version and RE intervals are enabled by default.